# SCSS Calculations Do Not resolve In Storybook

Tags: angular, sass, storybook

I'm using Storybook in an Angular Component Library. One of the components has the scss shown here:

[image]

```
margin-top: calc(($size / 2) * -1);
 margin-left: calc(($size / 2) * -1);
```

When I check the Storybook window, these two lines are crossed out in the inspector. I realize that "/" will be deprecated soon, so I have attempted to use the scss math module "@use sass:math" for math.div. There are other areas in the component library that also use math.div, but anywhere that it does it fails. Pic is an error example of this:

[image]

"SassError: Undefined function."

I have tried using the answer from this stackoverflow question:
[SCSS Modules not properly loading in Storybook for my Nextjs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673800/scss-modules-not-properly-loading-in-storybook-for-my-nextjs-app)
If I use this solution I get an error when I run storybook:

"ReferenceError: path is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add

```
@use "sass:math";
```

To the top of the file. [See also](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div)

Comment: This has already been done. The error shown has that at the top of the file. I've read the sass docs.